# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'-Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Tags: dart

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug' flutter run endlessly and finaly came up with "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1" this error

Answer (score 0):

for resolve this problem you need to follow some steps.

1. Go into the flutter folder and find 'flutter_console' batch file and click it.
2. Run the command 'flutter doctor', then resolve all issues by following given instructions, and make sure there is no issue left.
   3.check your current android sdk version.
3. Then go back to your project, find build.gradle file in android/app folder and fill the right compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wma3e.png).
4. Open project structure and change SDK version.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3If5.png)
5. And in the end change the excepeption type to FileNotFound.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIETX.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post screenshots of code but include the code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple.

1. Make sure your DNS Resolver config file is writable:
2. Open Terminal.
3. Type : sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
4. Change the IP address in the file to: 8.8.8.8
5. Press CTRL+X to save the file.
6. Now you run flutter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3yFN.jpg)